# Visually Representing input From a Flightstick in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a simple program that takes input from a standard flightstick (Logitech Extreme 3D Pro) and display which keys are being pressed. I've looked over the documentation for setting up a gamepad device but I haven't seen anyone successfully read values using Windows.Gaming.Input for a flightstick. I have some basic code that I thought would work based on a similar project that used an XboxOne Controller.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    FlightStick joystick2;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (FlightStick.FlightSticks.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Flightstick Found");
            joystick2 = FlightStick.FlightSticks.First();
            var reading = joystick2.GetCurrentReading();
        } 
    }
```

I have the writeLine test in there but it is never called so my guess is that the flightstick is never added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See the [FlightStick.FlightSticks Property Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.flightstick.flightsticks#remarks) part,

> This list is initally empty and will not list flight sticks even if they are already connected. After a short period this will return a complete list of flight sticks.

You should wait a short period for this list to show correctly or try to use the [FlightStick.FlightStickAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.flightstick.flightstickadded) event.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it takes forever to see if there is every a flight stick connected. I have not gotten it to work whatsoever. Do you have an example using FlightStick.FlightStickAdded?

Comment: I just did a test and ran a timer where it would continuously get and display the count of the list in a text box. After five minutes the count was still 0.

Comment: Is the `FlightStick.FlightStickAdded` event triggered?